# c# find class types in one list and write list values to other list

Tags: c#, list, class, lookup, exists

I have two lists that are saved to a class called ListType which is displayed below. I'm trying to match two lists onto each other on matching class type values. Both lists contain the county and act_loc class type so what I'm trying to do is where the county and act_loc from the fileList list equals the county and act_loc from the census file and if so I want to write all the class type data to the filelist list.

ListType class:

```
public class ListType
{
    public ListType()
    {
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string REGSID { get; set; }
    public string county { get; set; }
    public string act_loc { get; set; }

    public string hmonth { get; set; }
    public string hisnc { get; set; }
    public string hinc { get; set; }

    public string black00 {get; set;}
    public string asian00 { get; set; }
    public string hispanic00 { get; set; }
    public string pop2000 { get; set; }
    public string popden2000 { get; set; }
    public string totalunder18_00 { get; set; }
    public string sixtyfiveplus_00 { get; set; }
    public string percentforeign_00 { get; set; }
    public string percentsixteenplusinmanu_00 { get; set; }
    public string medhouseholdinc_00 { get; set; }
    public string totalbelowPOV_00 { get; set; }
    public string englishverywell_00 { get; set; }
    public string black10 { get; set; }
    public string asian10 { get; set; }
    public string hispanic10 { get; set; }
    public string pop2010 { get; set; }
    public string popden2010 { get; set; }
    public string totalunder18_10 { get; set; }
    public string sixtyfiveplus_10 { get; set; }
    public string percentforeign_10 { get; set; }
    public string percentsixteenplus_10 { get; set; }
    public string medhouseholdinc_10 { get; set; }
    public string totalbelowPOV_10 { get; set; }
    public string englishverywell_10 { get; set; }

    public string etype { get; set; }
    public string etypeText { get; set; }        
    public string edate { get; set; }
    public string fmp_amt { get; set; }
    public string newenftype_text { get; set; }
    public string finalenftype_text { get; set; }


    }
  }
```

one file parsed to a list:

```
public static List<ListType> census = new List<Listtype>();

using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Filename))
{
    read.ReadLine();
    while (!read.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = read.ReadLine();
        string[] splitline = line.Split(',');

        ListType l = new ListType();
        l.county = splitline[0].ToString();
        l.act_loc = splitline[1].ToString();
        l.black00 = splitline[2].ToString();
        l.asian00 = splitline[3].ToString();
        l.hispanic00 = splitline[4].ToString();
        l.pop2000 = splitline[5].ToString();
        l.popden2000 = splitline[6].ToString();
        l.totalunder18_00 = splitline[7].ToString();
        l.sixtyfiveplus_00 = splitline[8].ToString();
        l.percentforeign_00 = splitline[9].ToString();
        l.percentsixteenplusinmanu_00 = splitline[10].ToString();
        l.medhouseholdinc_00 = splitline[11].ToString();
        l.totalbelowPOV_00 = splitline[12].ToString();
        l.englishverywell_00 = splitline[13].ToString();
        l.hispanic10 = splitline[14].ToString();
        l.black00 = splitline[15].ToString();
        l.asian00 = splitline[16].ToString();
        l.sixtyfiveplus_10 = splitline[17].ToString();
        l.totalunder18_10 = splitline[18].ToString();
        l.englishverywell_10 = splitline[19].ToString();
        l.percentforeign_10 = splitline[20].ToString();
        l.percentsixteenplus_10 = splitline[21].ToString();
        l.medhouseholdinc_10 = splitline[22].ToString();
        l.totalbelowPOV_10 = splitline[23].ToString();
        l.pop2010 = splitline[24].ToString();
        l.popden2010 = splitline[25].ToString();

        census.Add(l);
    }
}
```

other file parsed to FileList list:

```
public static List,ListType> FileList = new List<ListType>();

using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Filename))
{
    read.ReadLine();
    while (!read.EndOfStream)
    {
        a++;
        string line = read.ReadLine();
        string[] splitline = line.Split(',');

        ListType l = new ListType();
        l.ID = splitline[0].ToString();
        l.REGSID = splitline[1].ToString();
        l.act_loc = l.ID.Substring(0, 2);
        l.county = splitline[2].ToString();
        l.hmonth = splitline[4].ToString();
        l.hisnc = splitline[5].ToString();
        l.hinc = splitline[6].ToString();
        l.etype = splitline[7].ToString();
        l.etypeText = splitline[8].ToString();
        l.edate = splitline[9].ToString();
        l.fmp_amt = splitline[10].ToString();
        l.finalenftype_text = splitline[11].ToString();

        fileList.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Foreach ListType county and act_loc in FileList I want to see if that same county and act_loc exists in census list (the same county and act_loc could exist multiple times in the FileList list it will only appear once in census list) and if so I want to write all the data from the census list to the FileList List. Having trouble doing this part. I want to loop through each record in FileList and if it exists in the census list I want to write the census data to the FileList record but in this below census does not exist when I'm writing to the data how can I access the census row so that I can write it to the fileList list.

```
foreach (ListType l in fileList)
{
    bool exists = census.Exists(p => p.county == l.county && p.act_loc == l.act_loc);

    if (exists)
    {
        //census data record to matching FileList record
        l.black00 = census.black00;
        l.asian00 = census.asian00;
        l.hispanic00 = census.hispanic00;
        l.pop2000 = census.pop2000;
        l.popden2000 = census.popden2000;
        l.totalunder18_00 = census.totalunder18_00;
        l.sixtyfiveplus_00 = census.sixtyfiveplus_00;
        l.percentforeign_00 = census.percentforeign_00;
        l.percentsixteenplusinmanu_00 = census.percentsixteenplusinmanu_00;
        l.medhouseholdinc_00 = census.medhouseholdinc_00;
        l.totalbelowPOV_00 = census.totalbelowPOV_00;
        l.englishverywell_00 = census.englishverywell;
        l.hispanic10 = census.hispanic10;
        l.black00 = census.black10;
        l.asian00 = census.asian10;
        l.sixtyfiveplus_10 = census.sixtyfiveplus_10;
        l.totalunder18_10 = census.totalunder18_10;
        l.englishverywell_10 = census.englishverywell_10;
        l.percentforeign_10 = census.percentforeign_10;
        l.percentsixteenplus_10 = census.percentsixteenplus_10;
        l.medhouseholdinc_10 = census.medhouseholdinc_10;
        l.totalbelowPOV_10 = census.totalbelowPOV_10;
        l.pop2010 = census.pop2010;
        l.popden2010 = census.popden2010;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reducing the amount of code. Looking at it, it seems like you add too much irrelevant information, which makes it less appealing to go through your question / code. Also read the following [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lengthy question so I'm not sure I'm answering what you're asking. But here's an attempt.

Looks to me like you're having trouble retrieving the correct census record. If so, this is what you want:

```
var cRecord = census.SingleOrDefault(p=>p.county == l.county && p.act_loc == l.act_loc);
if (cRecord != null) 
{
   l.black00 = cRecord.black00;
   // etc...
}
```

Furthermore, may I suggest using a Dictionary for your data, so that it's easier to look up than with linq queries? The only challenge with that is that you have a key consisting of two fields. You can then make a struct for your key of two values, or simply have string-key with a separator like pipe. So if your key is county = "mycounty" and act_loc = "myactloc", you could make a key "mycounty|myactloc" or some such.

Comment: yes this works but for some reason the records being written to census are not what they should. I'm stepping through where it writes the data to the list and its correct but when it returns the matching census like you've given me above its not what was written to census. Its very weird.